# How to display top visiting users for a page in Confluence?

Tags: macros, wiki, confluence

How can I show top visiting users for a page in Confluence? I've tried the macro "Top Users" but you can only set "Restrict to these Spaces".

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to display a list of the most frequent visitors to a page ON that page?

Comment: Yes, Top Users macro give me the statistic for the whole space

Answer (score 1):

The [ViewTracker macro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.bitvoodoo.confluence.plugins.viewtracker) will show page vistors. The [Tracking Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.confluence.plugin.tracking) is also useful. For more advanced collection of information use the [Google Analytics Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.go2group.plugins.confluence-ga). Alternatively, use [Piwik](http://piwik.org) with the tracking JS code inserted at a space or site level.

Comment: Are there any cloud add-ons to achieve this?

Comment: Not that I can see or have used. Theoretically you could clone the [smartics Piwik Integration macro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.smartics.piwik.atlassian.confluence.smartics-piwik/server/overview) and submit it to Atlassian to be loaded into the Atlassian cloud hosting.